# return a cell in the same row as activecell and first column of a selection in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

thanks in advance for your help. I'm new to VBA and I need to select the row header of an activecell -basically building this code, which doesn't seem to work in VBA:

```
Dim C as range ("I4")
Dim R as C.CurrentRegion
cells(C.row,R.Columns(1)).Select
```

I can't use `C.End(xlToLeft)` because I have another table on the left and, although there is one blank column dividing the 2 tables, this code jumps to the table on the left. Also, the first column of my table is not A, and I can't hardcode the column number.
Many thanks if you can help!
Silvia

Comment: Sorry formatting went weird: below I marked with // when I'm starting a new line:

Comment: `Cells([I4].Row, [I4].CurrentRegion.Column).Select` ?

Comment: Just for reference, in VBA the declaration and setting have to be on separate lines `Dim C as Range` and then `Set C = Range("I4")` http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1503/ranges-and-cells

Comment: No way we can help you if you don't show us visually the data you're dealing with thansk

Comment: Thanks both, sorry I'm new to this site and didn't know how to add any visualization. Yes the original code contained dim C as range and then set C=range("I4")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from that little that can be understood in your post, I'd guess you're after

```
Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns(1)).Select
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.row, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Column).Select
```

With no use of "helper" `range` variables (like yours `C` or `R`)

Should you *need* to use them, then the two alternatives become:

```
Set C = ActiveCell
Set R = C.CurrentRegion
Intersect(C.EntireRow, R.Columns(1)).Select
```

or

```
Set C = ActiveCell
Set R = C.CurrentRegion
ActiveSheet.Cells(C.row, R.Columns(1).Column).Select
```

---

but in any case you'd better not *select* anything and just:

- set it to some `range` variable:

  ```
  Dim myCell as Range

  set myCell = Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns(1))
  ```
- and then *use* it:

  ```
  myCell.Font.ColorIndex = 3
  ```

Comment: Many thanks, much appreciated! The solution works perfectly!

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I've just marked it as solved- excuse me again.